# Spotify embed press play button without user interacting with iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, spotify

I want to activate the Spotify embed (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/widgets/generate/embed/) without having the user click the play button. i have tried focussing the iframe and dispatching a space event to it, but that doesn't seem to work.
you can see that failed attempt here:

```
//bind an onclick event to all of the custom play buttons
document.querySelectorAll(".listPlay").forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('mouseup', e=> {
        //get the Spotify ID from the parent
        ID = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.spotid;
        //set the iframe src to the ID
        document.getElementById("spotPlayer").src = "https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/" + ID;
        //focus the iframe for starting
        document.getElementById("spotPlayer").contentWindow.focus();
    })
});

//as soon as the new iframe src loads, press space on it
document.getElementById("spotPlayer").addEventListener('load', e=> {
    document.getElementById("spotPlayer").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':32,'which':32}));
})
```

some example html to use with this

```html
<div data-spotId="7tFiyTwD0nx5a1eklYtX2J"><div><i class="material-icons listPlay">play_arrow</i></div></div>
<iframe src="" id="spotPlayer" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" class="" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this or come up with something? I am looking to do the same thing.

Comment: i eventually gave up and asked for a redesign that didn't include the non-interaction embed. I'd recommend you also ask for/make a redesign that just uses the default embed